# Bourne shell: send arguments $2 to $N to variadic function?

Tags: shell, variadic-functions, sh

Google has finally failed me. I cannot seem to find how to do this in Bourne shell scripting:

I am writing a shell script to handle all of my testing for a project. I've set up functions for each task that this script could do (build, run, clean, etc), and would like to pass any additional command-line parameters (besides the command itself) onto the desired function.

Example:

`./test.sh build -j` should pass `-j` into the `build` function.

A pseudo-code version of this logic would look like:

```
function build() {
   make $*
}

if [ $1 == 'build' ]; then
   build $2 -> $N
fi
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you could achieve this effect using the `shift` command. It will move all of the positional parameters down one place and drops the value of `$1` (so the value of `$3` gets moved to `$2`, the value of `$2` gets moved to `$1` and the value of `$1` is lost). Once you've done that you can just use `$@` to pick up the list of arguments you're actually interested in e.g.

```
function build() {
    echo "build with $@"
}

echo "Starting args are $@"
cmd=$1
shift

if [ "$cmd" = 'build' ]; then
    build "$@"
fi
```

Comment: You should use `"$@"` in the invocation of `build`, but otherwise spot on.

Answer (score 6):

```
function build() {
   make "$@"
}

if [ "$1" == 'build' ]
then shift        # Lose $1
     build "$@"   # Pass what was $2 .. $N
fi
```

Note the use of `"$@"` both in the function itself and in the invocation of the function.  I would argue that it is seldom correct to use either `$*` or `$@` without the double quotes or `"$*"`; only `"$@"` preserves the spacing of the original argument list, which matters if you have arguments that contains spaces.  If you're going to echo the arguments, then `echo "The arguments: $*"` is reasonable.  Otherwise, more than 90% of the time, you'd be better off using `"$@"`.  I also take an extremely conservative attitude towards quoting `"$1"` in the test operator; be cautious about omitting the quotes.

See also:

- [bash — being space safe when saving in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851877/bash-being-space-safe-when-saving-in-a-variable/)
- [${1:+"$@"} in /bin/sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154625/1-in-bin-sh/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are wanting to emit a more detailed error message, there's no need to test `$1` explicitly.  Just do:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
function build() {
   make "$@"
}

"$@"
```

If `$1` names a valid function, it will be called as desired.  If it does not, you'll get an error message which is probably not too bad, depending on your shell.