# Bash ARGS help - getting random error

Tags: linux, bash, args

Trying to set rules if a certain variable is put into place, can someone identify wtf I'm missing here?

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=($@)
if [ "$@" = "--cron" ]; then 
 echo "WORKS!";
    else echo "FAILS"
fi
```

output of `./test.sh`:

```
./test.sh: line 3: [: =: unary operator expected
FAILS
```

However, when I run `./test.sh --cron`, it works, and `WORKS` is output.

Comment: i'm noob but might it be this `==` ? .. nope its not.. just tested :/

Comment: @n0oitaf Bash should accept both `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I believe `"$@"` is too well quoted.

Try comparing against `"$1"`, or use:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=($@)
if [ "$*" = "--cron" ]; then 
    echo "WORKS!";
else
    echo "FAILS"
fi
```

Comment: @muistooshort: No; there's a huge difference between `"$*"` (a single string) and `"$@"` (as many strings as there are arguments).  See also [How to iterate over arguments in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225) and [Bash: being space safe when saving `"$@"` in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851877/bash-being-space-safe-when-saving-in-a-variable/5851983#5851983)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I missed the switch to `$*`. At least I've been reminded why I stopped writing shell scripts in favor Perl scripts.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this varies a bit depending on exactly what you're trying to do.  If you want to check whether the first argument is --cron, use this:

```
if [ "$1" = "--cron" ]; then
```

If you want to check whether the *only* argument is --cron, use this:

```
if [ "$*" = "--cron" ]; then
```

(Note that this is one of very few cases where `"$*"` is the right way to do something -- it expands to all arguments separated by spaces, but treated as a single word for parsing purposes.)

If you want to check whether *any* argument is --cron, use this:

```
cronopt=false
for argument; do
    if [ "$argument" = "--cron" ]; then
        cronopt=true
        break    # note: if you are scanning the arguments for other things too, remove this
    fi
done
if $cronopt; then
    ...
```

BTW, I'm not sure what you're using the `args=($@)` line for, but if you want to store the arguments in an array the correct way to do it is `args=("$@")` -- the quotes keep it from doing word splitting, filename expansion, etc before putting the args into the array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but only for the first element, of you want more you might have to do a `for` or `while` loop to iterate thru the arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
args=($1)
if [ $args ] && [ $args = "--cron" ]; then
  echo "WORKS!";
    else echo "FAILS"
fi
```

Comment: updated the answer but its not ideal, it will only work with the first argument